# Difference between template name and class template name

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a class template as follows

```
template <class t>
class Node{
    T data;
    Node<T>* nxt;
}
```

My question is when we want a pointer to class `Node`, why cant we use `Node* nxt` and what is the difference between `Node*<T> nxt` and `Node* nxt`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is valid to write `Node* nxt` in the class template definition, and it will have the same meaning as `Node<T>* nxt`. In general, inside the definition of a class template `C` with template parameters `T1`, `T2`, ... or such, you can simply write `C` and it will be equivalent to `C<T1, T2, ...>`. Try it, it will compile. (To be more precise, the type `Node` behaves as though it is declared as a nested type inside the class.)

*Outside* the class definition (and any member function definitions), you have to supply template parameters, rather than just writing `Node` by itself, because the name `Node` denotes a template, not a class; a class template is not a type, but a class obtained by instantiating a class template with template parameters is a type.

Comment: Upvoted for the `Node*` inside the class bit. I preferred explaining it with the outside part to make it clear for the OP the striking difference between them a template class and a type.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between `Node*<T> nxt` and `Node* nxt`?

There's no such type called `Node`. `Node<T>` would be a type, while `Node` is a template (not a type) from which you could make more types. Consequentially you could've a pointer to `Node<T>` but not to `Node`; hence `Node<T>*` is valid and `Node*` not.

> My question is when we want a pointer to class `Node`

You don't want a pointer to the template class `Node` but to some specific type like `Node<int>`. Also note that `Node<int>` and `Node<float>` are completely different types, similar to how different say `Animal` and `Pencil` types are.

> why cant we use `Node* nxt`

Because you can't make a pointer to a non-type entity. It's a template, not a type.